# How to use module.exports in Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, module.exports

In my next.js app, I am trying to expose this `env` object in my `next.config.js` following this [prescription](https://nextjs.org/docs#build-time-configuration) to my app;

```
//next.config.js

const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withCSS({
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 100000,
          name: '[name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    });
    return config;
  }
});

  //trying to expose the env {} below

    module.exports = {
      env: {
        DEVELOPMENT_DB_DSN: 'mongodb+srv://antonioHillfinder:foo@hillfinder-qjxuo.azure.mongodb.net/development?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
        PRODUCTION_DB_DSN: 'mongodb+srv://antonioHillfinder:bar@hillfinder-qjxuo.azure.mongodb.net/production?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
        TEST_DB_DSN: 'mongodb+srv://antonioHillfinder:foobar@hillfinder-qjxuo.azure.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
      }
    };
```

I tried this too:

```
var withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');


module.exports = {
  withCSS: withCSS({
    webpack(config) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 100000,
            name: '[name].[ext]'
          }
        }
      });
      return config;
    }
  }),
  env: {
    DEVELOPMENT_DB_DSN: `mongodb+srv://antonioHillfinder:foo@hillfinder-qjxuo.azure.mongodb.net/development?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
    PRODUCTION_DB_DSN: `mongodb+srv://antonioHillfinder:bar@hillfinder-qjxuo.azure.mongodb.net/production?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
    TEST_DB_DSN: `mongodb+srv://antonioHillfinder:foobar@hillfinder-qjxuo.azure.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
  }
};
```

And I'm trying to use them here:

```
var express = require('express')
var next = require('next')
var session = require('express-session')
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors')
var morgan = require('morgan')
var HttpStatus = require('http-status-codes')

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8016
var dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== `production`;

function processNODEENVCheckerAndServerRuntimeConfigSetter(ENV) {
  var environment,
    environments = {
      'production': () => {
        environment = process.env.PRODUCTION_DB_DSN; //trying to use them here
        return environment;
      },
      'test': () => {
        environment = process.env.TEST_DB_DSN; //trying to use them here
        return environment;
      },
      'default': () => {
        environment = process.env.DEVELOPMENT_DB_DSN; //trying to use them here
        console.log("environment ", environment);
        return environment;
      },
    };
  (environments[ENV] || environments['default'])();

  return environment
}

var db = processNODEENVCheckerAndServerRuntimeConfigSetter(process.env.NODE_ENV)

var NextApp = next({ dev })
var handle = NextApp.getRequestHandler()

var mongoose = require('mongoose')

NextApp.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const app = express()
    mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

    mongoose.connection
      .on('connected', () => {
        console.log(`Mongoose connection open on ${db}`)
      })
      .on('error', err => {
        console.log(`Connection error: ${err.message}`)
      })

    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
    app.use(morgan('dev'))

    app.use(cookieParser())

    session({
      secret: 'very secret 12345',
      resave: true,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
    })

    app.use(cors())

    app.use('/auth', require('./auth'))

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res)
    })

    app.use(errorHandler, function (error, req, res, next) {
      res.json({ message: error.message })
    })

    app.listen(PORT, err => {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
  })
```

In the end the app just breaks and I get this error...

```
environment  undefined

Compiled successfully!

Note that pages will be compiled when you first load them.
{ MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at new MongooseError (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/mongooseError.js:10:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:519:11)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:314:15)
    at NextApp.prepare.then (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/server/index.js:68:14)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  message:
   'The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.',
  name: 'MongooseError' }
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Not sure why I get `undefined` from `console.log("environment ", environment);` in the `var db = processNODEENVCheckerAndServerRuntimeConfigSetter(process.env.NODE_ENV)`
 statement/function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `env` option in **next.config.js** will only make the environment variables available at build time.

To have environment variables available to your server, you can put your environment variables in a `.env` file in the root of your project:

```
DEVELOPMENT_DB_DSN="mongodb+srv://antonioHillfinder:foo@hillfinder-qjxuo.azure.mongodb.net/development?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
PRODUCTION_DB_DSN="mongodb+srv://antonioHillfinder:bar@hillfinder-qjxuo.azure.mongodb.net/production?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
TEST_DB_DSN="mongodb+srv://antonioHillfinder:foobar@hillfinder-qjxuo.azure.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

Then you can use the **dotenv** package to load it:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

```
npm i dotenv
```

...and add this at the top of your server file:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Thereafter, your environment variables will be available on your server.

---

Note, the `env` option in **next.config.js** is to make environment variables available during a build and can be used like this:

```
// next.config.js

const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withCSS({
  webpack(config) {
    // ...
    return config;
  },
  env: {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. That didn't work. Is there anything I need to add into my `server/index.js`?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. The `env` option in **next.config.js** will only make those variables available at build time. I've updated my answer with another solution.

Comment: Thank you! So what is the first part of the answer accomplishing? Before you realized my problem?

Comment: You don't need the `env` in **next.config.js** unless you need specific environment variables during a build. As you only need them on the server, **dotenv** is the way to go.

Comment: Oh build — meaning the client?

Comment: Yes, when you build the client files :)